# Target by value in on edit function

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am creating a sheet where i need a timestamp, everytime a cell value changes to "x". The timestamp need to be one cell on the right of the "x". I have mutiple column where you can type x..

I have tried it by using Headers, but it dosent seem to work?Could it be because the places where you can type "x" is not right benith the header? Can anyone help me out or suggest another method?

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Mandagstræning") {
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Tid") + 1;
    var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf("dato") + 1;
    if (dateCol = "x" && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == orderCol) {
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "MM-dd-yyyy HH.mm.ss"));
    }
  }
}
```

Right now i dont get anything out, when i change a value to x. And my Headers are on first row in the sheet.

Here is an exsample of my sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Rtbqs08Xw5VxA6DRZQ6PnQtsOPZJbV4YGcLfpkEuvA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the spreadsheet application you are using this with?

Comment: I am using google sheets - if that is what you are asking about. Nothing special otherwise. Just macro's in there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. You can see it working in a [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lrhyj0-O4zxGgDxlM_oQp-6ziT7_KN3Icgl4UZfkjNA/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Mandagstræning") {
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); // changed
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Tid") + 1;
    var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf("dato") + 1;
    if (sheet.getRange(rowIndex, orderCol).getValue() === "x") { // changed
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "MM-dd-yyyy HH.mm.ss"));
    }
  }
}
```

The key was the two lines that are marked as `// changed`. For the first one, I only wanted the 1 row range, so I added in the number of rows as 1 for the third parameter. For the second one, you needed to get the value of the correct cell and use the comparison equality operator (`===`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`).

#### EDIT: after seeing the updated sheet

I tweaked the code in your example sheet as follows:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Mandagstræning") {
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, editColumn, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf("dato") + editColumn;
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Tid") + editColumn;
    if (sheet.getRange(rowIndex, orderCol).getValue() === "x") {
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "MM-dd-yyyy HH.mm.ss"));
    }
  }
}
```

You will notice that I am looking for the first matching order and date columns starting from the active cell's column. Then, if the value in the order column is `x`, the value in the first matching date column after that is set to the current date.

Comment: I see it woorking in your demo sheet and it is exactly what i am looking for. But it still is'nt woorking on my sheet
I have date and time in example B2 and B3 and again in E2 and F2 and so on troughout the sheet. I need it to be able to do it throughout the sheet,

I also tried moving them up, but i stil is'nt working.

Comment: @PernilleSundsEskildsen Can you share an example of your sheet (with any private data removed) on here?

Comment: Yeah two seconds - I can get it to work on the first row, but not on the scond with the "x".

Comment: it should be up in the text by now. As you can see it works on column B perfectly - Thank you.

Comment: @PernilleSundsEskildsen Updated my answer and that example sheet with working code.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if you can do a piece of code that will allow the script to run eventhough the column is protected?

Comment: @PernilleSundsEskildsen That is a separate question, I'm afraid. And no, I don't, sorry.